# Mongos server setup error

Tags: mongodb, sharding

When i run following command for mongos setup its give me error.
my command:

```
D:\TOOLS\MongoDB\bin>mongos.exe --configdb localhost:30000 --chunkSize 1
```

its give me following error.

```
2014-12-18T12:03:15.890+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock    'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.
2014-12-18T12:03:20.146+0530 [LockPinger] cluster localhost:30000 pinged successfully     at Thu Dec 18 12:03:20 2014 by dis
tributed lock pinger 'localhost:30000/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41', sleeping for   30000ms
2014-12-18T12:03:21.894+0530 [Balancer] distributed loc    'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' acquired, ts : 5492
7531e3528ef9a325cc6d
2014-12-18T12:03:21.895+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock     'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.
2014-12-18T12:03:27.904+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' acquired, ts : 5492
```

7537e3528ef9a325cc6e
2014-12-18T12:03:27.905+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.
2014-12-18T12:03:33.911+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' acquired, ts : 5492
753de3528ef9a325cc6f
2014-12-18T12:03:33.913+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.
2014-12-18T12:03:39.922+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' acquired, ts : 5492
7543e3528ef9a325cc70
2014-12-18T12:03:39.924+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.
2014-12-18T12:03:45.935+0530 [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' acquired, ts : 5492
7549e3528ef9a325cc71

Comment: I don't see any errors. What is the problem?

Comment: Actually i cant got what this indicates...Balancer] distributed lock    'balancer/CI5W8P111402:27017:1418884250:41' unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error listed in the log content you posted. What is the reasoning for installing a mongos (router) without a reference to the config server(s)? It is presumed if you are using a mongos, as opposed to mongod, that you are using sharding and you should setup your config servers first and then reference them when setting up the mongos. Here is the command line I use to setup mongos.

```
mongos --configdb <paste IP address here>:27019 --config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --logpath c:\mongodb\log\log.txt --port 27017 --install
```